# Python code to count dropdown list count in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find list count in below Xpath (drop down list):

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='macro-param-div']/div/ul/li/input"))
```

If I click on this path I get drop down list. I am trying below code from google but getting error as below:

Code:

```py
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select=UI.Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[14]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div/ul/li/input"))

fo = select.all_selected_options
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on input
```

Please suggest correct code how to use select method on xpath.

Comment: I believe this exception message is rather straightforward. You are using the `Select()` function on an HTML element that has the `<input>` tag, rather than the `<select>` tag.

Comment: Oh ok , could you please suggest how to get count on above html element that has input tag .

Comment: You can likely find how to get a count of `<input>` tags in an HTML page with python from some existing stackoverflow question. If not, you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: ok , I am unable to find solution in stackoverflow . Will post as separate question in another 90 minutes as it is not allowed imemdiately . Appreciate a lot if you can answer here for same .